# Angular 6 queryParamMap with filter is not working when refreshing the page

Tags: filter, parameters, angular6

As the subject states, queryParamMap with filter is not working when refreshing the page. I am using queryParamMap along side a filter, to show certain categories. This works fine when clicking on a category, but I would expect it to continue working if the user refreshes the page.

The following is the html:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <div name="categoryList" class="list-group">
      <a
        *ngFor="let c of (this.categoryObj | keyvalue); let j = index"
        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
        [class.active]="category === c.key"
        routerLink="/products"
        [queryParams]="{ category: c.key }"
      >
        <span>{{ c.key }} </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredProducts; let i = index">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card product-card">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="{{ oshopUrl + 'uploads/' + item.product_image }}"
              alt="{{ item.product_image }}"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.name }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{ item.category }}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{ item.price | currency }}</p>
              <a
                class="btn btn-success"
                href="#"
                (click)="incrementCartState()"
                >Add to Cart</a
              >
              <a
                class="btn btn-success"
                href="#"
                (click)="decrementCartState()"
                >Remove from Cart</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      <div *ngIf="(i + 1) % 2 === 0" class="w-100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following in the constructor is what makes it possible to click on a category, which filters the products:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
  this.category = params.get("category");

  this.filteredProducts = this.category
    ? this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category)
    : this.products;
});
```

However, if I reload/refresh the page, then all the products are shown. The following is subscribe to a method in product services, which fills the two arrays

```
this.prdSrvc.getAllProducts().subscribe(resProd => {
  this.filteredProducts = this.products = resProd.products;
});
```

I have tried to move the queryParamMap to onNgInit thinking that it might be a matter of timing, as well as having them in both, but no matter what, the products are only filtered if I click on one of the categories.

BTW, when I refresh the page, the correct Category is highlighted which corresponds to the queryParamMap. It's as if this.category is not being defined in time for the products to be filtered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a timing issue and I needed to place the queryParamMap after the products array was filled:

```
this.prdSrvc.getAllProducts().subscribe(resProd => {
  this.filteredProducts = this.products = resProd.products;
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.category = params.get("category");

    this.filteredProducts = this.category
      ? this.products.filter(p => p.category === this.category)
      : this.products;
  });
});
```